# Why do i need to almost use Isset?

Tags: php, forms, validation, isset

Why every time I need to almost use `isset()` I couldn't understand why the php always has notice and warnings following is the two codes and I don't understand why we need to `isset()`.

Please explain briefly because I'm a low thinker as you can see I declare the variable `x` but the PHP said undefined this is only in checkbox and radio button didn't encounter in textbox and even in declaring variable we need to declare it at the top like this `$var='';`

Please explain my mind is in confusion right now I don't know what is true or false I know `isset` is use to check if the variable is set or null but why it is important. Why in checkbox it doesn't give me error [HERE IS THE ERROR WITHOUT ISSET()](http://prntscr.com/89unpp)

**WRONG CODE**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $x=$_POST['burger'];                    
            if($x == ''){
                echo 'Please fill it up';                   
            }else{
                foreach($x as $z){
                        echo $z.'<br>';

                }
            }             
      }
?>
```

**RIGHT ONE**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){            
        if(isset($_POST['burger'])){
            $x=$_POST['burger'];    
        }
        if(empty($x)){
            echo 'Please fill it up';           
        }else{
            foreach($x as $z){
                    echo $z.'<br>';

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You use `isset()` to check if a value is defined and isn't `null`.  Programming involves a lot of `null` checking when it's possible that a value hasn't been set, this isn't just in PHP.

Comment: You get a notice when your form doesn't actually send a field `burger` along. Check for typos there. (And if you're running into such things constantly, you'd better hold off using `isset` everywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

**Php isset() is used to check whether a variable is set or not. So without isset check, $x is not defined which results in error.(uninitialized variable $x)**.

Explanations below,

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){  //checks if $_POST["submit"] is set, preventing $_POST uninitialized errors

                        if(isset($_POST['burger'])){ //checks if $_POST["burger"] is set, preventing $_POST uninitialized errors
                            $x=$_POST['burger'];  //$x will be always set, bcoz its inside isset($_POST["burger"])   
                        }
                        if(empty($x)){
                            echo 'Please fill it up';

                        }else{
                            foreach($x as $z){
                                    echo $z.'<br>';

                            }


                        }


                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an array. Normally, when you try to access a key of an array that doesn't exist, you get an error. `isset` allows you to check if the key exists. That way you can write an if that throws a human readable error or uses a default value in case the posted value doesn't exist.

In alternative to `isset`, you could use:

```
if (array_key_exists('Submit', $_POST)) {
}
```

`isset` is more a generic way to perform the check, and it's often used for this goal. But it has some side effects too! It can for instance return false, even if the key technically exists.

By using a specific function like `array_key_exists`, your code is a bit more verbose and more specific, making it easier to understand what is going on, and you won't have those forementioned side effects.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a variable in PHP which wasn't initalized before, there will be a warning issued. So isset() is used to check if the variable exists or not.

But there is a problem with your solution, because in case when `$_POST['Burger']` isn't set, $x will also not be set, it will be better to use `if(isset($x)){` instead of `if(empty($x)){`